# Graficos com ruido no arduino no plotter

Tags: c, c++, arduino

Implemente código que simule a velocidade de um carro como sinal mais ruído, com 50 elementos. O valor da velocidade aumenta de modo linear de 0-50 km/h. A amplitude do ruído é de ± 1 km/h. Os valores são enviadas à consola com precisão de três dígitos significativos.  Apresente exemplo de resultados na consola e no plotter.
Como faria o ruído?

```
float maximo = 50;
float minimo = 0;  
float variac = 1;
float percent = ?;

float N = (maximo - minimo) / abs(variac);
float amplitude = (maximo - minimo)/2;
float offset = (maximo + minimo)/2;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(2400);
    for(int i=0;i<=N;i++){
        Serial.print(variac*i +minimo);
        Serial.println(percent*amplitude*random(-100,101)/100.0);
        Serial.println(percent*amplitude*random(-100,101)/100.0 + variac*i +minimo, 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Creio que esses vídeos possam ajudar com o conceito: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLKqXX49sH6-ELYsur__uaS8dW34BB7vF6

Answer (score 1):

No plotter:

```
void setup( void )
{
    Serial.begin(2400);

    // Inicializa gerador de numeros aleatorios
    randomSeed(analogRead(0));

    // Para cada amostra...
    for( int velocidade = 0; velocidade <= 50; velocidade++ )
    {
          // A mesma amostra de velocidade eh lida 10 vezes
          for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
          {
            // Calcula-se o nivel de ruido da amostra
            float ruido = random( -1000, 1001 ) / 1000.0;

            // Plota a velocidade e o ruido com precisao de 3 casas decimais
            Serial.println( velocidade + ruido, 3 );
          }
    }
}


void loop(void)
{
}
```

Saída:

[image]

No Console:

```
void setup( void )
{
    Serial.begin(2400);

    // Inicializa gerador de numeros aleatorios
    randomSeed(analogRead(0));

    // Para cada amostra...
    for( int velocidade = 0; velocidade <= 50; velocidade++ )
    {
      // Calcula-se o nivel de ruido da amostra
      float ruido = random( -1000, 1001 ) / 1000.0;

      // Plota a velocidade e o ruido com precisao de 3 casas decimais
      Serial.println( velocidade + ruido, 3 );
    }
}


void loop(void)
{
}
```

Saída:

```
-0.796
0.175
2.548
2.006
3.923
5.839
5.796
7.301
8.109
8.238
10.871
11.063
11.400
13.843
13.863
15.671
16.680
17.731
18.784
19.046
19.381
20.521
21.053
23.935
23.351
24.343
26.938
27.396
27.579
28.941
29.939
30.906
32.392
32.823
33.875
34.347
36.084
37.373
37.376
39.756
39.978
41.940
42.991
42.460
44.442
45.191
45.103
47.454
47.376
49.420
49.166
```